# node, express angular routing

Tags: angularjs, express, routes

get request in angular:

```
$http.get('/twitter')
    .success(function(response) {
      console.log("here is the response: ", response);
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log("oh no something went wrong: ", err);
    });
```

routing in node/express:

```
app.get('/twitter', function(req,res) {
  console.log("at the twitter endpoints");
  res.send("at the twitter endpoint");
});
```

not sure why my routing isn't working, but I keep getting a cannot get /twitter error

Comment: Go to the `/twitter` URL directly in a web browser so that Angular is no longer a factor. Make sure you have some logging enabled on the server (e.g. `morgan`) so you can see all the requests coming in. Nothing strikes me as obviously wrong with your server code, are you sure the file has been saved and the server restarted?

Comment: you have not define the baseURL - http://localhost:port/twitter